# Creating instances of structure on the run?

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I'm playing around with structures and found a way to assign instances of structures IDs of type int.

```
struct test{
 int x;
 int y;
}

assign(struct test *instance, int id, int x2, int y2)
{
 (instance+id)->x = x2;
 (instance+id)->y = y2;
}

print(struct test *instance, int id)
{
 printf("%d\n", (instance+id)->x);
}


main()
{
 struct test *zero;
 assign(zero, 1, 3, 3);
 print(zero, 1);
}
```

When executing this code, it does what it should, but it gives me a Segmentation fault notice. What can I do about this?

Comment: note `(instance+id)->x` == `instance[id].x`

Comment: three things are wrong with main() 1) the correct syntax is 'int main()'  2) passing '1'  will result in the second entry in 'zero' being set, I.E. skipping the first entry. 3) currently 'zero' points to 'nothing in particular'  I.E. it needs to point to some allocated memory, for instance: struct test *zero = malloc(2*sizof(struct test) );  And then check the returned value from malloc() to assure the operation was successful  Then make the call to assign().  Note: be sure to call free(zero); before exiting the program, to avoid a memory leak.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to allocate memory for the structures before you can use them.

You can use "automatic storage":

```
// You can't change COUNT while the program is running.
// COUNT should not be very large (depends on platform).
#define COUNT 10

int main()
{
    // Allocate memory.
    struct test zero[COUNT];

    assign(zero, 1, 3, 3);
    print(zero, 1);

    // Memory automatically freed.
}
```

Or you can use "dynamic storage":

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int count;
    struct test *zero;

    // You can change count dynamically.
    count = 10;

    // Allocate memory.
    // You can use realloc() if you need to make it larger later.
    zero = malloc(sizeof(*zero) * count);
    if (!zero)
        abort();

    assign(zero, 1, 3, 3);
    print(zero, 1);

    // You have to remember to free the memory manually.
    free(zero);
}
```

However, you should remember to put return types on your functions... leaving them out is reminiscent of C from the 1980s...

```
void assign(struct test *instance, int id, int x2, int y2)

void print(struct test *instance, int id)
```

Comment: What I'm trying to do is I want to create multiple structures, so that the user may for example input the ID 3 and assign values to attributes, much like in a database. Is there no way to create infinite structures while the program is already running?

Comment: @John: Linked lists are not necessary.  Arrays are fine.

Comment: Yes, but it is up to you to keep track of have many you have at any one instance in time and whether you need to `realloc` to get more. Simply create some initial amount `#define NSTRUCT 256` then allocate that many pointers `struct test **mytest = calloc (NSTRUCT, sizeof (*mytest));` then as you need a struct, allocate `mytest[0] = calloc (1, sizeof (**mytest));` Add as needed `1,2,3..` until you reach `NSTRUCT-1` then `realloc` to `2*NSTRUCT` and keep going. That is one solid approach to having as many as you need.

Comment: @John: As I said, linked lists are not necessary, arrays are fine.  Do you know how `malloc()` works?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: It sounds like you are trying to solve a problem that was not posed in the question.

Comment: @DietrichEpp Pardon me Sir. I understand you correctly now. Sorry for Spamming.

Comment: @DietrichEpp, please re-read the comment immediately preceding my first. Specifically **"Is there no way to create infinite structures while the program is already running?"** -- That is the comment I was responding to. When allocating pointers, you know what `calloc` does and why it allows iteration without having to keep track of counters. As for the struct itself, `malloc/calloc` is largely irrelevant. I prefer `calloc` for the initialization it provides (especially when dealing with array allocation where it protects against a spurious read from an uninitialized element).

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: Please clarify.  What is the problem with my answer that you are trying to solve?  `malloc()` will already let you create arrays as large as you like, until you run out of address space.

Comment: @DietrichEpp, there is **nothing** wrong with your answer -- I voted for it. My comment was in direct response to the OP's question (in comment **1**) **"Is there no way to create infinite structures while the program is already running?"** It was in no way related to the sufficiency of your answer.

Comment: Okay.  In the future, please indicate who you are responding to by putting the @ user name in the comment.  Otherwise, it looks like you are responding to the answer.